# how to update quantity of products in the cart via javascript?

Tags: commerce

I have the module that changes the quantity of products inside the card via ajax but I need to change it also outside, as on the picture, [image]

the code that changes the quantity after reload of the page are as follows

```
$variables = array(
        'order' => $order,
        'contents_view' => commerce_embed_view('commerce_cart_block', 'defaults', array($order->order_id), $_GET['q']),
      );
      $count = commerce_line_items_quantity($wrapper->commerce_line_items, commerce_product_line_item_types());

      $quantity = 0;

      foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item) {
        if (!$line_item instanceof EntityMetadataWrapper) {
          $line_item = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_line_item', $line_item);
        }
        $types = array('product');

        if (empty($types) || in_array($line_item->type->value(), $types)) {
          $quantity = $quantity + $line_item->quantity->value();

        }
      }

      $prod_count = t($quantity);  

      if ($prod_count > 0){

        $icon = '<div class="cart-icon"></div><span class="cart_popup_count">'. $count . '</span>';
        $content = '<div id="cart-popup" style="display:none;">' . theme('commerce_cart_block', $variables) . '<div class="popup-arrow"></div></div>';
        $content = '<div class="wrapper">' . $icon . $content . '</div>';  
      }elseif (variable_get('commerce_popup_cart_show_empty_cart', 0) == 1){
        $content = commerce_popup_cart_block_view_get_empty_cart($variables);
      }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to changes this numbers simultaneously inside and outside the card.

This is the code that changes quantity inside the card

```
  function _commerce_popup_cart_add_to_cart_ajax_callback($form, $form_state) {
  commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_submit($form, $form_state); //Call the add to cart form to actually add the product
  $res = _commerce_popup_cart_ajax_cart_reload(); //Retrieve the new cart view

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#block-commerce-popup-cart-commerce-popup-cart .cart-empty-block", "<div class='cart-contents'></div>");
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#block-commerce-popup-cart-commerce-popup-cart .cart-contents', $res);
  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands); 
}

function _commerce_popup_cart_ajax_cart_reload() {
  global $user;
  $view_name = 'commerce_cart_block'; // The name of the view we are going to load commerce_cart_block
  $args = array(commerce_cart_order_id($user->uid));  // Array of arguments we set for the view. Only one argument in our example. your actual view may require additional 

  //arguments which you may need to set   
  $displayId = 'default'; // The display id of for the view.
  // Call the views_embed_view function to returned themed view output
  $res = views_embed_view($view_name, $displayId, $args);
  return $res;
}
```

Comment: i did not read all your code ,, but i want to understand .. you know how to update card as php .. but you do not know how to do it as js ?? right ?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: I wrote such a code but it didn't help me $('.cart-selector').on('change', function(e)) {
$('.your-another-place').text($(this).text());
}

Comment: so i thing you have to create new simple module which has hook_menu to create new link like  mysite/card/update/total  .. then call this link as Ajax in your js

Answer (score 1):

- Create new simple module like my_updater_card
- add hook_menu
- add php function to update the card
- call this function from ajax

  ```
  <?php
  /**
   * Implements hook_menu().
   * see hook_menu()
   * see menu_example
   */
  function my_updater_card_menu()
  {
      $items['my_updater/card/%'] = array(
          'page callback'         => 'my_updater',
          'page arguments'        => array(2),
          'access arguments'      => array('put your permission here'),
      );
      return $items;
  }

  function my_updater($newTotal){
      //check if this request come from ajax => if not => ignore it
      //here put your php code to update the card
      //then return results true/false to ajax caller
  }
  ?>
  ```

Ajax

```
        $.ajax({
               url: 'my_updater/card/[new total here]',
               type: "GET",
               success: function (data) {
                 //do total refresh here 
               }
        });
```